# Programming tokens that expires on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, set, cloud

in my architecture, I've two lambda functions.
The first one takes as input a username, generates an ID and returns it to the user invoking it.
The other one receives a username and an ID, checks if it was the username to generate the ID in the last 5 minutes and if yes returns true.

I'm not really sure how to implement this. I need some sort of "set" allowing me to push the obj ("username",ID,timestamp) and something that removes IDs from this set when timestamp is older than 5 minutes ago.

Is there some AWS service already existing that comes to your mind when thinking about this simple scenario?

At the moment, the best alternative I have is to create a little DB to store the objects and a lambda function to clean up old objects invoked each 5 minutes.

P.s. as this is just a side project I'm doing to learn AWS I would really appreciate if your proposed solutions manage to stay in the free tier :D

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to broadly replicate Cognito user pools.  As opposed to trying to create your own component why not look to create a project making use of cognito.  Take a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html